# C# - Detect time of last user interaction with the OS

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, system-tray, idle-processing

I'm writing a small tray application that needs to detect the last time a user interacted with their machine to determine if they're idle.

Is there any way to retrieve the time a user last moved their mouse, hit a key or interacted in any way with their machine?

I figure Windows obviously tracks this to determine when to display a screen saver or power down, etc, so I'm assuming there's a Windows API for retrieving this myself?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

[GetLastInputInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646302(VS.85).aspx).  Documented at [PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetLastInputInfo).

Comment: +1 for PInvoke.net - I didn't know about that resource until now.

Comment: doesn't work for touch screens without mouse and keyboard activity

Answer (score 59):

include following namespaces

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

and then include following

```
internal struct LASTINPUTINFO 
{
    public uint cbSize;

    public uint dwTime;
}

/// <summary>
/// Helps to find the idle time, (in milliseconds) spent since the last user input
/// </summary>
public class IdleTimeFinder
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);        

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern uint GetLastError();

    public static uint GetIdleTime()
    {
        LASTINPUTINFO lastInPut = new LASTINPUTINFO();
        lastInPut.cbSize = (uint)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(lastInPut);
        GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInPut);

        return ((uint)Environment.TickCount - lastInPut.dwTime);
    }
/// <summary>
/// Get the Last input time in milliseconds
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
    public static long GetLastInputTime()
    {
        LASTINPUTINFO lastInPut = new LASTINPUTINFO();
        lastInPut.cbSize = (uint)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(lastInPut);
        if (!GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInPut))
        {
            throw new Exception(GetLastError().ToString());
        }       
        return lastInPut.dwTime;
    }
}
```

To convert the tickcount into time you can use

```
TimeSpan timespent = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ticks);
```

Note. This routine uses the term TickCount but the values are in milliseconds and are so not the same as Ticks.

From [MSDN article on Environment.TickCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> Gets the number of milliseconds elapsed since the system started.

Comment: You get the idle time in milliseconds, not ticks.

Comment: As kennyzx mention correct way to get timespan is 
`TimeSpan timespent = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ticks);`

Comment: When I create a class I cannot get any objects out of the class to set to a value, can you post an example of how you would use this after you instantiate the class?

Answer (score -1):

Code:

```
 using System;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

 public static int IdleTime() //In seconds
    {
        LASTINPUTINFO lastinputinfo = new LASTINPUTINFO();
        lastinputinfo.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(lastinputinfo);
        GetLastInputInfo(ref lastinputinfo);
        return (((Environment.TickCount & int.MaxValue) - (lastinputinfo.dwTime & int.MaxValue)) & int.MaxValue) / 1000;
    }
```