# Do something after some inactivity on the computer

Tags: c#

Let's say I want my program to do something after some inactivity.
For example let's say that the user of my program won't press any keys / or move the mouse for X seconds, then after these X seconds it'll show a MSGBox, "you were away for X seconds".

I think it'll have to detect both mouse & keyboard on any program.. but how, is there any fast way to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037595/c-sharp-detect-time-of-last-user-interaction-with-the-os

Comment: This is similar to `idle` status in Google chat when you are inactive. You can use the same :)

Comment: @Meds asking for deleting **what**? Anyway here is another way to [detect](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9104/How-to-check-for-user-inactivity-with-and-without)

Comment: @bonCodigo Nothing, it's ok :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest google search brought up this:

http://dataerror.blogspot.co.il/2005/02/detect-windows-idle-time.html
Should work

Comment: Solved I found that too : 
 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9104/How-to-check-for-user-inactivity-with-and-without  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Timer Elapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx)

Define a public timer, keep it running, and reset it on form events or control events like MouseMove, KeyPress, etc