# How to detect the User is idle with regard to my C# application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to know please when the user is not using my application.

I have been looking to this [GetLastInputInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037595/c-sharp-detect-time-of-last-user-interaction-with-the-os) but this manages the interaction with the OS and not only my application.

My application has many forms and I would like to avoid adding handlers to every form to check for **MouseHover** or **PressKey** events. At least it's very difficult.

Is there any other way please to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: You could create a `BaseForm` which implements some events and just inherit from that form. This way you'd have your idle-handling in every form with implementing it just once.

Comment: Basically you need `IMessageFilter` which is mentioned in the linked duplicate question.