# Find focus on media element in wpf as window media player

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created video player with help of Media Element control in wpf as below,

[image]

And then added some player control such as progress Bar, play, pause, stop buttons Like as below image. This buttons set enabled only mouse down process.

[image]

I want to hidden this buttons when user nothing do any activities on video screen like as windows media player.

Please suggest your idea. Thanks

Comment: i think you looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037595/c-sharp-detect-time-of-last-user-interaction-with-the-os this solution. You can decide to display your control bar based on GetLastInputTime().

Comment: Petty pictures, but this question is missing technical details like a code/xaml example. Also, please suggest your (incomplete) ideas before you ask others for their ideas.