# Auto Invoke the command of button of window developed in wpf after a specific time

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I have a requirement where if nothing has been changed on the window which is developed in wpf, the Continue button should be auto invoked after a specific time which will load next window.

Comment: First, detect if the user has been idle example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037595/c-sharp-detect-time-of-last-user-interaction-with-the-os, then raise an event or Invoke a Command to load the next Window

Comment: Why don't you use a timer?