Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'uint' and Use of unassigned local variable in C#
I have an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'uint'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)" and "Use of unassigned local variable 'lASTINPUTINFO'"
Please Guide me
How can I solve the error and I am also a beginner in C# or There was something wrong in the implementation of the code I created or indeed the code I used was wrong
Thanks
The code below I use :
namespace Utilities
{
    internal class Win32
    {
        public Win32()
        {
        }

        public static uint GetIdleTime()
        {
            LASTINPUTINFO lASTINPUTINFO = new LASTINPUTINFO()
            {
`Error below line code Use of unassigned local variable`
                cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf<LASTINPUTINFO>(lASTINPUTINFO)
            };
            Win32.GetLastInputInfo(ref lASTINPUTINFO);
`Error below line code Cannot implicitly convert type long to uint`
            return Environment.TickCount - lASTINPUTINFO.dwTime;
        }

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.None, ExactSpelling=false)]
        private static extern uint GetLastError();

        [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.None, ExactSpelling=false)]
        private static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

        public static long GetLastInputTime()
        {
            LASTINPUTINFO lASTINPUTINFO = new LASTINPUTINFO()
            {
`Error below line code Use of unassigned local variable`
                cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf<LASTINPUTINFO>(lASTINPUTINFO)
            };
            
    }
}



a.) you presumably defined lASTINPUTINFO.dwTime as long but your code want to return an uint there but your "math" does int - long and that will result in a long not a uint. Either cast or decide that uint is the wrong type here. b.) you can't use a variable while its beeing initialised. Simply create the lASTINPUTINFO without the initializer and set cbSize afterwards.

Be aware that in NET managed code we tend to not use unsigned types explicitly even if it looks a better fit. Not every language based on .NET  knows about those types.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71354997/14171304

Let's see the definition for Environment.TickCount, it's Int32 so that we might do what @dr.null did in his case to use (uint)Environment.TickCount instead, could you pls try return (uint)Environment.TickCount - lASTINPUTINFO.dwTime; ?

cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf<LASTINPUTINFO>()

@dr.null , Thank you for your recommendation of the answer link

@TinyWang , Thanks for your respond answer

@Jimi , Thanks for your respond answer

@dr.null , Actually, I have a previous post  link that has not been solved, maybe I need advice from you or indeed the post has no solution

@TinyWang , Actually, I have a previous post  link that has not been solved, maybe I need advice from you or indeed the post has no solution

@Jimi , Actually, I have a previous post  link that has not been solved, maybe I need advice from you or indeed the post has no solution

Thanks for @dr.null , @TinyWang , @Jimi problem solved
namespace Utilities
{
    internal class Win32
    {
        public Win32()
        {
        }
        public static uint GetIdleTime()
        {
            LASTINPUTINFO lASTINPUTINFO = new LASTINPUTINFO()
            {
                cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf<LASTINPUTINFO>()
            };
            Win32.GetLastInputInfo(ref lASTINPUTINFO);
            return (uint)Environment.TickCount - lASTINPUTINFO.dwTime;
        }

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.None, ExactSpelling=false)]
        private static extern uint GetLastError();

        [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.None, ExactSpelling=false)]
        private static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

        public static long GetLastInputTime()
        {
            LASTINPUTINFO lASTINPUTINFO = new LASTINPUTINFO()
            {
                cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf<LASTINPUTINFO>()
            };
            if (!Win32.GetLastInputInfo(ref lASTINPUTINFO))
            {
                throw new Exception(Win32.GetLastError().ToString());
            }
            return (long)lASTINPUTINFO.dwTime;
        }

        public static long GetTickCount()
        {
            return (long)Environment.TickCount;
        }

        [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.None, ExactSpelling=false)]
        public static extern bool LockWorkStation();
    }
}



